# How to programmatically set the ForeColor of a label to its default?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm using VS2010 C# ASP.NET

To programmatically change the ForeColor of an asp:Label named `lblExample` to 'Red', I write this:

```
lblExample.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
```

After changing the ForeColor, how do I programmatically set the ForeColor of the label to its default (that comes from the css file)?

Remark:
the label has no CSS entry (class or ID specific style). The color is inherited.

Comment: You could store the 'default' ForeColor in a variable and then revert to it when you want to change back. ie/ before you initially change it something like... oldColor = lblExample.ForeColor. Then lblExample.ForeColor = oldColor.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Easy

```
if (lblExample.ForeColor != System.Drawing.Color.Red)
{
    lblExample.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
}
else
{
    lblExample.ForeColor = new System.Drawing.Color();
}
```

Comment: Or use `Color.Empty`, which is equivalent to `new Color()`.

Comment: Michael Liu- I'm probably missing something, 'cause : 'System.Drawing.Color' does not contain a definition for 'empty'

Comment: @Different111222: Make sure `Empty` is capitalized. [See the MSDN documentation.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color.empty.aspx)

Answer (score 21):

You can also use below format:

```
Label1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#22FF99");
```

and

```
HyperLink1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#22FF99");
```

Answer (score 10):

The default (when created with the designer) is:

```
label.ForeColor = SystemColors.ControlText;
```

This should respect the system color settings (e.g. these "high contrast" schemes for visual impaired).

Answer (score 6):

You can also use

```
lblExamlple.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(0,255,0);
```

Comment: Use only RGB color mode

Answer (score 1):

For example `summer` :

```
lblSummer.foreColor = color.Yellow;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
labelname.ForeColor = Color.Colorname;   ­­­­
```

Comment: `Color` do not have `Colorname`.

Comment: @GáborBakos its meant to be replaced by a name of a color - "Red" for example

Answer (score -1):

ARBG­­­ = Color(alpha,Red,Blue,Green) you can set any value you want to but don't forget the Maximum value are 255­

---

Example :

`labelname.ForeColor = Color.FromArbg(100,200,30);`